# How to extract values in a JSON file into separate columns in a dataframe row

Tags: python, json, pandas, json-normalize

```
data = json.load(open("C:/Users/<username>/Downloads/one-day-run-record.json","rb"))

df = pd.json_normalize(data)[["summaries", "tags.com.nike.weather", "tags.com.nike.name", "start_epoch_ms", "end_epoch_ms", "metrics"]]
df
```

My main goal is to extract the values in the `metrics` column. To understand the structure of that column you can use the line right below

`df.metrics[0]`

In the code below you can see the metrics separated by type. I want all the values that are stored in `values` for the types `steps`, `speed` and `pace`

```
prov = pd.json_normalize(df.metrics[0])
prov
```

For exemple: in type `steps` you have this (As you can check in `df.metrics[0]`):

Full data at https://pastebin.com/4eNscEsh

```
{'type': 'steps',
  'unit': 'STEP',
  'source': 'com.nike.running.android.fullpower',
  'appId': 'com.nike.sport.running.droid',
  'values': [{'start_epoch_ms': 1605042906780,
    'end_epoch_ms': 1605042907751,
    'value': 13},

   {'start_epoch_ms': 1605042907780,
    'end_epoch_ms': 1605042911754,
    'value': 11},

   {'start_epoch_ms': 1605042911772,
    'end_epoch_ms': 1605042915741,
    'value': 6},

   {'start_epoch_ms': 1605042915741,
    'end_epoch_ms': 1605042918713,
    'value': 13},

   {'start_epoch_ms': 1605042918713,
    'end_epoch_ms': 1605042920746,
    'value': 5},
    
...}]}
```

I want a row with the values `[13, 11, 6, 13, 5, ...]`, each of these values in a different dataframe column.

Is it too difficult to do? How could I do that? I've tried multiple ways, but I am totally new to `.json` files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The `'values'` column in `'metrics'` is a `list` of `dicts`

  - In order to extract `'value'`, the `lists` need to be expanded with `.explode()` so that each `dict` is on a separate row.
  - `'values'` is now a column of `dicts`, which needs to be converted into a dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
import json
from pathlib import Path

# path to JSON file
p = Path('test.json')

# load the JSON file into a python object
with p.open('r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

# convert the metrics key into a dataframe
df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'metrics', ['id', 'start_epoch_ms', 'end_epoch_ms'])

# explode the values column
dfe = df.explode('values').reset_index(drop=True)

# convert the column of dicts into a dataframe and join it back to dfe
dfj = dfe.join(pd.DataFrame(dfe.pop('values').values.tolist()), rsuffix='_values')

# groupby the type column and then aggregate the value column into a list
dfg = dfj.groupby('type')['value'].agg(list).reset_index(name='values_list')

# merge the desired list of values back to df
df = df.merge(dfg, on='type').drop(columns=['values'])

# select the final types
desired = df.loc[df['type'].isin(['steps', 'speed', 'pace'])]

# to separate each value in the list to a separate column
final = pd.DataFrame(desired.values_list.to_list(), index=desired.type.to_list())

# display(final.iloc[:, :5])
               0          1         2          3         4        ...
steps  13.000000  11.000000  6.000000  13.000000  5.000000        ...
speed   0.000000   0.000000  0.000000   0.000000  0.000000        ...
pace    8.651985   8.651985  6.542049   6.542049  6.173452        ...

# aggregate calculations
final.agg({'steps': 'sum', 'speed': 'mean', 'pace': 'mean'}, axis=1)

steps    2676.000000
speed       9.657251
pace        5.544723
dtype: float64
```

### Screenshots of dataframes

- There's to much data in the dataframe to post text examples, so here are some screenshots to given an idea of the break down

#### Initial `df`

- 9 total rows
  [image]

#### `dfe`

- Exploding the column creates a total of 699 rows
  [image]

#### `dfj`

- Create a dataframe from the column and joined it to `dfe`
  [image]

#### `dfg`

- Creates a list of the desired values
  [image]

#### Final `df`

- `values_list` are the desired values
  [image]

#### `desired`

- Selected only the desired `'types'`
  [image]

Comment: I am just having a little problem. When I run ``df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'metrics', ['id', 'start_epoch_ms', 'end_epoch_ms'])`` I get this error: ``TypeError: {'id': 'test', 'type': 'run',[...]'app_id': 'com.nike.sport.running.droid', 'source': 'com.nike.running.android.fullpower'}]} has non iterable value 1605042901601 for path ['start_epoch_ms']. Must be iterable or null.``. Do you have any idea why it worked for you but did not work for me?

Comment: @ApoloReis I can run it with the original sample from https://pastebin.com/4eNscEsh. See if you can run that sample. Also, make sure pandas is updated to version 1.2.1